# merging measurements with different time tags

Tags: dataframe, merge

Suppose you have two data frames p,q with which each contain a time series (time/value pair), that is:

```
    > p
      t val1
    1 1   11
    2 2   11
    3 3   11
    > q
        t val2
    1 1.4   22
    2 1.8   22
    3 3.2   22
```

I am looking for a call (free of handcoded for-loops) to integrate the two time series into a single time sorted data frame. My expected (or: hoped-for) result is:

```
        t   val1 val2
     1  1   11   NA
     2  1.4 NA   22
     3  1.8 NA   22
     4  2   11   NA
     5  3   11   NA
     6  3.2 NA   22
```

base::merge(p,q,by="t",sort=T) comes close to do the job but certainly fails if column t has time values that are not identical in p and q.
Any hint would be appreciated. All the best, J.

Comment: use `all=TRUE` in `merge`.

Comment: Er, how simple... (－‸ლ) 
Didn't read "?merge" careful enough.   The "all.x = all, all.y = all" plus "all = L is shorthand for all.x = L and all.y = L" left me unenlightened. Stupid me, thank you!